# requests: disable auto decoding

Tags: python, python-requests

Can you disable the auto decoding feature in `requests` version 1.2.3?

I've looked through the documentation and couldn't find anything, I'm currently experiencing a gzip decode error and want to manually debug the data coming through the request.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can access the raw response as [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) like this:

```
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
resp.raw.read()
```

In order to use [`raw`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raw) you need to set `stream=True` for the original request.

Note that `raw` is a [file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) and reading from [`response.content`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.content) will affect its [seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) cursor, so if you read `response.content` then try to `response.raw.read()`, it will return an empty bytes object.

See [FAQ: Encoded Data?](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/community/faq/#encoded-data) and [Quickstart: Raw Response Content](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) in the Requests documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.raw.stream(1024, decode_content=False):
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
```

This way, you will avoid automatic decompress of gzip-encoded response, and still write it to file chunk by chunk (useful for getting big files)