# Use python Requests to download an compressed tar.gzfile and unzip it using tar

Tags: python, python-requests, gzip, tar

I need to use request call to download a tar gz file, I found out that requests.get automatically decompresses the file, I tried to use the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18364322/2455308) but when I try to decompress it using tar it says it is not in gzip format.

I tried the following approaches:

```
response = requests.get(url,auth=(user, key),stream=True)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(target_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.raw)

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(target_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.raw)

raw = response.raw
with open(target_path, 'wb') as out_file:
    while True:
        chunk = raw.read(1024, decode_content=True)
        if not chunk:
            break
        out_file.write(chunk)
```

All of the above while decompressing throw the error:

```
$ tar -xvzf /tmp/file.tar.gz -C /

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Note: Cannot use [urllib.open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19602990/2455308) as I need authentication etc and I have to use requests library

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just need to change `f.write(response.raw)` to `f.write(response.raw.read())`

Try the code below, this should give you a correct tar gz file.

```
import requests

url = 'https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xlrd/xlrd-0.9.4.tar.gz'
target_path = 'xlrd-0.9.4.tar.gz'

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(target_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.raw.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

For a built-ins only solution (no 3rd party [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)), one can use [`urllib.request.Request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request):

```py
from urllib import request

url = "https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xlrd/xlrd-0.9.4.tar.gz"
target_path = "xlrd-0.9.4.tar.gz"

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request
# NOTE: Transfer-Encoding: chunked (streaming) will be auto-selected
with request.urlopen(request.Request(url), timeout=15.0) as response:
    if response.status == 200:
        with open(target_path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.read())
```